# How do you import a macro defined in the current crate into a doc test?

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to write a doc test that uses a macro that I define in the crate I'm writing the doc test in. I've written this synthetic example that reproduces the problem:

````
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! my_vec {
    ($($element: expr),*) => {
        crate::MyVec::from_vec(vec![$($element),*])
    }
}

pub mod my_vector {
    #[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
    pub struct MyVec<T> {
        vec: Vec<T>
    }

    impl <T> MyVec<T> {
        pub fn from_vec(vec: Vec<T>) -> Self {
            Self { vec }
        }

        /// ```
        /// # // what can I put here to make the doc test compile?
        /// let mut v = my_vec![1,2,3];
        /// v.clear();
        /// assert_eq!(v, my_vec![]);
        /// ```
        pub fn clear(&mut self) {
            *self = my_vec![]
        }
    }
}
pub use my_vector::MyVec;

fn main() {
    let mut v = my_vec![1,2,3];
    v.clear();
    assert_eq!(v, my_vec![]);
}
````

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=57fa59edf1cc4fa0afd8879b04adc2cb)

If I run the code, the `main` function runs properly as expected, but the doc test containing the same code causes the following error if I try to run the tests:

```
---- src/lib.rs - my_vector::MyVec<T>::clear (line 19) stdout ----
error: cannot find macro `my_vec` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:21:13
  |
4 | let mut v = my_vec![1,2,3];
  |             ^^^^^^

error: cannot find macro `my_vec` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:23:15
  |
6 | assert_eq!(v, my_vec![]);
  |               ^^^^^^
```

How can I import the macro into the test?

Comment: You should also use `$crate`: `$crate::MyVec::from_vec(vec![$($element),*])`.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0060248526c1e1472e1765a16e09080)